# "Тем не менее"

Tags: пунктуация

В предложениях такого типа "И(,) тем не менее, я не знаю ответа на этот вопрос" нужна ли запятая после И?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае **тем не менее** - наречное выражение со значением «все-таки, несмотря на это». Не требует постановки знаков препинания. Например: 
*Мюллер долго наблюдал за тем, как медленно, еле заметно, но тем не менее неуклонно лучи двигались по комнате.* Ю. Семёнов, Экспансия-I. *Вместо уроков географии ходит в гости к знакомой кокотке, что тем не менее ничуть не вредит ее образованию.* Н. Тэффи, Французский роман. *Несмотря на то, что Ягозин был кровным детищем Петербурга, дышал со дня рождения воздухом Невского проспекта и сосал молоко охтенской кормилицы, он весь тем не менее состоял из одной быстроты и юркости.* Д. Григорович, Карьерист.

Но в других случаях **тем не менее** может быть и союзом со значением «но, однако». Тогда синтаксические конструкции с союзом «тем не менее» выделяются знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Сравните: 
*Хотя письменная отчетность о поступающих в лазарет и возвращающихся в эскадроны лошадях и лежала на мне и барон требовал большого порядка по этой части, тем не менее смотреть за лазаретом не входило в круг моих непременных обязанностей.* А. Фет, Семейство Гольц.
(Грамота.ру)

Comment: Хм. Я тут подумал: а разве "и" не может быть частицей? Может быть и частицей, и союзом.
Все-таки знак препинания в этом предложении можно рассматривать как факультативный.

Comment: А разве в этом примере не следует ставить запятую перед "и барон"?